# Splitting field of $x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

One of my qualifying exam practice questions asks the degree of the field extension of the splitting field $K$ of $x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.  Since the roots of $x^3-3$ are all just the cube root of the times the cubic roots of unity, I think the extension is of degree three, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ already contains the cubic roots of unity.   But then when I start thinking of the size of the basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$,  I start thinking of the square roots times the cube roots, and I get the degree of the field extension as much more than three, and now I'm all confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automorphisms of a splitting field](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231704/automorphisms-of-a-splitting-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\rho=(-1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$ is a generator of the cube roots of unity, and that 
$$x^3-3=(x-3^{1/3})(x-3^{1/3}\rho)(x-3^{1/3}\rho^2).$$ And $\rho$ lies in $Q(\sqrt{-3})$ So the coefficients of the factored form of $x^3-3$ all lie in the latter field with  the real number $3^{1/3}$ adjoined to $Q(\sqrt{-3})$. So it looks like the degree is 3, considered *over* $Q(\sqrt{-3})$